# Filezilla tabs are hard to read with dark theme

Tags: gnome, filezilla

The tabs with the "Queued Files" etc. are displayed inconsistently to the rest of the theme (see image). Everything else uses a more "flat" design, whereas those tabs have a gradient and are kind of hard to read on the dark theme. (And it looks ugly imho)

I guess it's a problem with dark themes, since it looks okay with light themes (e.g. normal adwaita).
Although there is still the background gradient, the contrast between background and text is big enough.

System:
Manjaro Gnome (v41.3) with Wayland
Adwaita-dark Application Theme (similar with other dark themes)
FileZilla 3.58.0 (from the Manjaro Community Repo)

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem on KDE. While the tabs luckily never change and would be easy to remember, you could create a bug report for that.

Comment: I already created a bug report about 3 years ago https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/11861

Comment: Well, that is sad, considering that this looks like a pretty small change. I'll have a look into it.

Comment: @mashuptwice Did you have any luck?